# convert time 12 hour format to 24 hour format and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, time

I want a js script that converts inputted time to 24 hour format or 12 hour format.

Example,

- time is entered as `10_10_am` result should be:-

  `10:10 AM` (12 hr format) and `10:10` (24 hr format)
- time is entered as `10_10_pm` result should be:-

  `10:10 PM` (12 hr format) and `22:10` (24 hr format)

Comment: what have you done so far??Place your code in the question!!!its not that that difficult.Just create some custom conditions and apply logic accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## **HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="convert 12 hr"/>
<input type="button" id="b2" value="convert 24 hr"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

## **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function am_pm_to_hours(time) {
        console.log(time);
        var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
        var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
        var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
        if (AMPM == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
        if (AMPM == "am" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
        var sHours = hours.toString();
        var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
        if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
        if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
        return (sHours +':'+sMinutes);
    }

    function hours_am_pm(time) {
        var hours = time[0] + time[1];
        var min = time[2] + time[3];
        if (hours < 12) {
            return hours + ':' + min + ' AM';
        } else {
            hours=hours - 12;
            hours=(hours.length < 10) ? '0'+hours:hours;
            return hours+ ':' + min + ' PM';
        }
    }
    $('#b1').click(function(){
         var n = $('#textbox1').val();
         var n1 =n.split('_');
         var time = hours_am_pm(n1[0]+n1[1]);
        $('#result').text(time);
    }); 
    $('#b2').click(function(){
        var n = $('#textbox1').val();
         var n1 =n.split('_');
        var time = am_pm_to_hours(n1[0]+':'+n1[1]+' '+n1[2]);
        $('#result').text(time);
    });

});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xEuUR/

**updated after  Adrian P 's comment**

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xEuUR/4

```
function hours_am_pm(time) {
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var min =  Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
    if (hours < 12) {
        return hours + ':' + min + ' AM';
    } else {
        hours=hours - 12;
        hours=(hours < 10) ? '0'+hours:hours;
        return hours+ ':' + min + ' PM';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle gives me 4::0 for a conversion of 16:00

Comment: @AdrianP. ty for letting me know that i have fixed the issue and updated answer. SEE demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xEuUR/4
>

Comment: Now 03:00 PM gives me 03:00 The 12hour convert it is working. Thanks.

Comment: As I said there is one more error: 03:00 PM gives 03:00 instead of 15:00 when I clicked on Convert to 24hours. Thanks.

Comment: The function 'hours_am_pm' does not handle input such as '930,615'.` //handles the time with length 3 ( 930,615)
      ` if(time.length ==3) {
      //appends 0 to convert time to 4 digit format
      var hours = 0+time[0];
      var min = time[1] + time[2];
    } else {
      var hours = time[0]+time[1];
      var min = time[2] + time[3];
    }`   condition needs to be added

Comment: This solution works reasonably good for me, however I would like to point out a few things :

* It always expects an empty symbol between minutes and AM/PM, so this would not work "12:34AM", but "12:34 AM" will

* When converting to AM/PM, the extra 0 at the beginning is only added for PM

8:22 => 8:22 AM
20:22 => 08:22 PM

Comment: Also, please update your answer to include the upper and lower case of "AMPM" by changing this line `if (AMPM.toLowerCase() == "pm" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any specific function that already exists, but this is fairly easy to write.

Considering your input is always `##_##_pm` or `##_##_am` you can split this string on every `_` and grab first value as `hours`, `second` as `minutes` and compare the third 
and

if it's pm add `12 hours` to the hours variable for `24 hr format`.
You need a function that takes 2 parameters (format and string)
It will look something like this:

```
function timeFormat(format, str){
    var timeParts=str.split("_");
    if(format==12){
       return timeParts[0] + ":" + timeParts[1] + " " + timeParts[2];
    }else if(format == 24){
       var hours = timeParts[0];
       if(timeParts[2] == "pm")
           hours += 12;
       return hours + ":" + timeParts[1]
    }
}
```